# Angular 2 Accessing Grandchild component API

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to use PrimeNG's Table (Turbo) component, and want to have the table height fit available space.  It doesn't currently handle that well, but have I have mostly worked around it (using element-resize-detector).

However, I've found that when the scrollbar disappears (or appears), the headers get out of alignment.  There is code in the component that adds some margin, based on the scrollbar, but I can't call it because it is not exposed, near as I an tell.  While this seems to be a bug, I'd like to find some temporary workaround.  I can use a ViewChild to get at the Table, but not at the grandchild, ScrollableView. Is there really no way to access this within angular 2?  I understand that they are trying to promote encapsulation, but I'm just looking for a workaround till such time as this is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

The only thing I've seen that comes even remotely close to what you are after is `ContentChildren`, which allows a second parameter of `{ descendants?: boolean }`. However I could not get it to work nor could I find any documentation on the `decendants` parameter. *In short, I don't believe what you are trying to achieve is possible.*

**Original Answer**

If you're just looking for a dirty solution then you can always use an `rxjs/Subject`.

You could create a service that holds the subject and inject it into both the grandparent and grandchild. When you need to do something on the child, fire an event from the parent, making sure that the child is subscribed to the subject, and then the child handles the event by calling the method you need called.

Comment: In order to use a service to solve this, I would have to inject that service into ScrollableView, and have it subscribe to the subject  However, that's not my component; it's part of PrimeNG.  I would prefer to avoid forking the codebase and maintaining it.  I just want to get at the component (either through some feature in angular, or maybe through the DOM?) and call the method.

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying. I've tried messing with a lot of things including `ContentChildren`, which allows a second parameter of `{ descendants?: boolean }` but came up short in every way. I don't believe what you're trying is possible!

Comment: So, from what I've gathered, your comment is correct.  It isn't possible.  I'd mark your comment (Not possible) as the accepted answer, but its in a comment, and the original answer isn't what I was getting at. Care to edit it?